# Prevent getUserMedia audio feedback on Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, getusermedia

When a video and audio stream from a webcam is acquired by `getUserMedia` and assigned to a `<video>` element, I can see and hear myself. The audio track however turns into a feedback noise.

The `HTMLMediaElement.muted` or `HTMLMediaElement.defaultMuted` however doesn't seem to apply to a live camera feed.

The feedback also occurs even if the `<video>` element is not connected to the DOM (created by JS).

How can I mute the audio feedback without disabling the stream's audio (`getUserMedia` with `audio:false`) alltogether? The audio should be usable with an `AudioContext` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Add `muted` attribute to `video` element (`<video id="video" muted />`).

Comment: That was what I've already done (see question). So it seems I've encountered a bug then. Which may be solved, as I've never have this problems today it seems.